# How to create a custom filter to search on nested arrays on Angular 1.3.6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have this array `sports`, json looks like:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "LIVE Betting",
    "priority": 0,
    "leagues": []
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "NBA",
    "priority": 3,
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": 5932,
        "parent": 1000,
        "name": "NBA",
        "sport": {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "NBA"
        },
        "lineType": "G",
        "priority": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "part": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "College Basketball",
    "priority": 4,
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": 2599,
        "parent": 1000,
        "name": "NCAA BASKETBALL",
        "sport": {
          "id": 24,
          "name": "College Basketball"
        },
        "lineType": "G",
        "priority": [
          0,
          4
        ],
        "part": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 2631,
        "parent": 1000,
        "name": "NCAA BASKETBALL ADDED GAMES",
        "sport": {
          "id": 24,
          "name": "College Basketball"
        },
        "lineType": "G",
        "priority": [
          1,
          4
        ],
        "part": "0"
      },
      ...
```

within that array you can see other array named `"leagues": [{...}]` which contains an `Object`, my filter is searching fine through the top array which is `sports` but once I try to find through the `"name"` within `leagues` array then my app shows up a message that the filter is empty.

I just realized that this is happening because I am using the version `1.3.6` of Angular but I am unable to change it until the Ionic people upgrade it to the `1.3.8`, I made [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OjLf2XlS1RBk2tZa5fdo?p=preview) with the version `1.3.8` and it works properly, but if you change the version on that same Plnkr to the `1.3.6` automatically stop searching through `leagues.name` and only works with `sport.name`, and [here is a Plnkr with the version 1.3.6](http://plnkr.co/edit/giUXAZtJiZbQav3C2dYF?p=preview), on both Plnkrs try searching `Greece`, in the first with the version 1.3.8 works, but in the version 1.3.6 just the message `no sports to show` comes up

```
<input type="search" ng-model="query">

<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
        <!--this array works fine-->
        <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues">
        <!--this one not works at all-->
        {{league.name}}
      </div>
</div>
```

I've been trying all the ways already, with a `resolve`, with different models, etc and actually I just realized that I need a custom filter so I would like you to give me a hand because I do not where to start from with it.

or is there any easier way ?

Comment: i think this this is the commit where they include deepcompare https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bd28c74c1d91c477a86f10fe36576cba0249e6ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/marklagendijk/lodash-deep  for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query">

    <div role="alert" ng-show="sportfilter.length==0">No sports to show</div>

    <div ng-repeat="sport in sportfilter=(sports  | filter:matchNameDeep(query))" ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
      <div>
        <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
      </div>

      <div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues" on-tap="goToLines(league)">
        {{league.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


$scope.matchNameDeep = function(query) {
  return function(sport) {
    return !query || sport.name.match(new RegExp(query, "ig")) || sport.leagues.some(function(element, index, array) {
    return element.name.match(new RegExp(query, "ig"))
    });
  }
};
```

see here it working with angular 1.3.6  http://plnkr.co/edit/0w9PYbDsOz0mHBdVldZt?p=preview

Comment: it was case sensitive - changed it to case-in-sensitive now - and updated plunker- now it will work